# iOS Create Push Notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification

Is it possible to create a push notification from within an app instead of relying on a web service?

For example, imagine an app that polled for location changes and notified a user when they've entered a geofenced area.

Does a push notification *always* have to go through apple's service? Or is it possible to trigger an internal event which would then cause a push notification to fire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for are "Local" notifications, as opposed to "Push" notifications.

More here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1

Answer (score 1):

You won't do that with Push Notifications, but you can with Local Notifications.  Have the app poll in the background for location changes and alert the user when they enter the area.  It is definitely doable.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) is the documentation on polling for location changes, in foreground and background.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward tutorial for UILocalNotifications incase your looking for one.

http://iphone-rahulvarma.blogspot.com/2012/03/uilocalnotifications-tutorial.html